# Using JASidePanels

Tags: ios, objective-c, jasidepanels

I'm trying to use JASidePanels (from github) in my project. I'm using centerviewcontroller, leftviewconrtoller and JASidePanelController based on library example. I've placed UIView  on centerviewcontroller then i added IBOutlet.

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myview;
```

I need to change its color when the menu appears. How can i do it? I can change the color of centerviewcontroller.view but I can't change the color of  UIView i've placed on centerviewcontroller.view. I can change the color in centerviewcontroller

```
  self.myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];.
```

but I do not know how to do this from JASidePanelController.

Comment: how about changing the color in `showLeftPanel:`?

Comment: I know where to change. I do not know how to access myview.backgroundcolor

Comment: `MyViewController* vc = self.centerViewController; vc.myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UIViewController` is called `MyViewController`.

The following will allow you access to the `centerViewController` to change its `backgroundColor`:

```
MyViewController* vc = self.centerViewController;
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```